# How to import icons from the names received by the API?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic.io (I guess similar in operation to react icons). Before using the icon, it is necessary to import it:

Example:

`import { chevronBackOutline, chevronForwardOutline, speedometerOutline } from 'ionicons/icons';`

The API from the backend sends me a response in JSON with information on what icon to use (the name of the icon). For example:

```
{
  parentIcon: "chevronBackOutline"
}
```

Based on this received name, how can I import this icon?

Comment: you can import all icons as: `import * as icons from 'ionicons/icons';`
and call it like: `icons['chevronBackOutline']`.
i have not done this but hope this will work.